# Powershell scripts for checking VMs for crashes

Tags: java, powershell

I'm looking for some help in determining whether a VM has crashed, I'm currently using a java program that iterates 200+ VMs over multiple servers by running Powershell scripts and determining whether they have crashed or not. Any ideas on scripts I should use to determine whether these VMs have crashed or not.

Currently using scripts to get the logged in user, if that does not respond I then attempt a new PSSession , if this fails then assume it has crashed.

The method is 80-90% accurate in detecting, but there are some that are flagged as crashed that aren't. Is there any recommendations or pointers that can help? 
Cheers.

Edit: Different checks are required for different versions of Windows. I found that Test-WSMAN works well with Windows Server 2012-2016 and getting a WMIObject works well for 2008 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would find something where the value changes constantly.  Monitoring the network connection for example.

You can use :

```
(Get-NetAdapterStatistics).ReceivedBytes
```

The value you get from that changes constantly - same goes for all 4 values you get from that command.

If the query doesn't get any response, it's probably crashed.  If the network card hasn't sent or received anything for a certain period of time, chances are you have a crash.

Adding this to the checks you already perform would raise your level of accuracy, I think.

Comment: Found this worked well along with  running Test-WSMan -ComputerName
Seems to be a great way of catching frozen VMs as an all else fails